# curl (60) peer’s certificate issuer is not recognized Linux CentOS

Tags: python-3.x, linux, curl

I am getting `curl (60) peer’s certificate issuer is not recognized error` while doing `request.get(url,verify='/xxx.cer')` in my py script. python version : 3.6.8, PIP is updated.

Also tried steps mentioned in https://ep.gnt.md/index.php/curl-60-peers-certificate-issuer-is-not-recognized/

Verify=False is also not working.